# How to initialize anonymous structures in class constructor?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, anonymous-types

How could i initialize anonymous structures ?

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() : m_var.var_1(1)
    {
    }
    
private:
    struct 
    {
        int var_1;
        int var_2;
    }m_var;
};
```

The above code give me this error when i try to compile it:

```sh
main.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
main.cpp:6:16: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
    6 |     A() : m_var.var_1(1)
      |                ^
      |                (
main.cpp:6:16: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘.’ token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize the whole object, not the subobjects of the data member. This is not just special for anonymous `struct`. E.g.

```
A() : m_var{1, 0} // m_var.var_1 and m_var.var_2 are initialized as 1 and 0
{
}
```

And since C++20 we can use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) to specify data member of the `struct` in initialization. E.g.

```
A() : m_var{.var_1=1, .var_2=0} // same effect as above
{
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning the availability of [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers), which looks more similar to what OP tried to do.